# Android - JSON get single value

Tags: android, json

I have a single JSON object like this

```
"stringData"
```

with no column names or anything just a single string

I'm confused how to get that value with no column names

**edit the following code to get that single value ?**

```
private void showJSON(String response){
    String value="";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        value = jsonObject. ??????
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textViewResult.setText("Value:\t"+value);
}
```

Comment: If response already has exact String you want to display then why not just do textViewResult.setText("Value:\t"+response);

Answer (score 1):

your response is a string but not in json form. so convert this string into jsonObject give JSONException. So. you can do two things 1. first use this string without making jsonobject OR 2. send string in json form from server than convert the string into jsonobject and use.